# How to view Blob Storage logs in Azure App Insights?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights, azure-storage-explorer

I just uploaded a blob to an Azure Blob Storage Container. Almost immediately, there was an entry in the .log file when viewed using Azure Storage Explorer:
[image]

**How do I view these logs (or similar) using Application Insights?**

The only App Insights table that seems to have any data is the `AzureActivity` table, but it only shows the `List Storage Account Keys` activity, not the actual filename/size/etc of the uploaded blob.

[image]

`StorageBlobLogs` is empty (this is the most reasonably *sounding* table where the data would be):

[image]

`AzureMetrics` is also empty:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement can be achieve, but maybe you need to do some custom filter.

First, the log analysis of storage will not log these things.

You need to send logs to `Log Analytics workspace`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And the operation name will be a little different, such as 'create blob' will change to 'put blob'(This is because the most basic interactive behaviors are implemented through rest api. So you need to find the rest api request corresponding to each behavior. After that you can know the name of the corresponding behavior.).

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/monitor-blob-storage?tabs=azure-portal#send-logs-to-azure-log-analytics) is the official doc, you can do a check.