# Azure Blob Storage V2 , unusual API calls from Azure Function App, after upgrade

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have been using the Azure Function App consumption plan with Azure Blob Storage V1 for some time, with no problem.

Two months ago, we changed over to Azure blob Storage V2 and all of a sudden we noticed a drastic increase in costs.

After some investigation, we found that there are several 10's of thousands of API calls for
GetBlob,
GetBlobProperties,
GetBlobServiceProperties,
ListBlobs,
PurBlob,
RenewBlobLease.

My functions do not use this particular storage account for any storage, as I am using an external account for tables.

Has anyone experienced such an issue or know why these API calls are being called?

Comment: Not really enough info. Enable logging for storage account (under Diagnostic settings). You'll get detailed info on who's making those calls.

Comment: We are seeing exactly the same problem. Did you ever found a solution?

Comment: I moved it back to Blob storage 1, it seems V2 does increase the cost. I am still not sure, but there seems to be an increase in usage

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this storage is also the AzureWebJobsStorage of your function app?

The files of your function app will be stored in the AzureWebJobsStorage.

You can follow this to check the source of the request:

[How to view Blob Storage logs in Azure App Insights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67291310/how-to-view-blob-storage-logs-in-azure-app-insights/67296547#67296547)

Comment: Yes this account, is set in my function apps AzureWebJobsStorage  setting.

Comment: @user8400863 I suspect it is because of the version update of your function app. How do you deploy your function app? And have you checked the source of the request that access the storage?

Comment: I am deploying as a zip deploy from Visual Studio.

Comment: @user8400863 Have you check the source of the request by the link i post?:)

Comment: This is an example of what APIs are being called:

https://...:443/remotehub-leases/taskhub.json
https://...:443/remotehub-leases/default/remotehub-control-02
https://...:443/remotehub-leases/default/remotehub-control-02?comp=lease&amp;timeout=10